# Android Mobile/Wear App onMessageReceived Called Multiple Times for One Message

Tags: android, message, wear-os

I've got a basic Android Wear app that successfully uses the Wearable Data Layer to send and receive messages between the mobile device and Wear.

However, any time I send a message (from Mobile or Wear device) the other end receives it multiple times (like anywhere from 5-17).  Why is it not just received once? As far as I can tell it's only sending once.

After successfully connecting, here is my **code to Send Message** (same on both ends):

```
private void sendMsgToWear(final String strMsg){

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Node>>(){

        @Override
        protected List<Node> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return getNodes();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Node> nodeList) {
            for(Node node : nodeList) {
                Log.v("DEVELOPER", "......Phone: Sending Msg: " + strMsg + " to node:  " + node.getId());

                PendingResult<MessageApi.SendMessageResult> result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        node.getId(),
                        strMsg,
                        null
                );

                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                        Log.v("DEVELOPER", "......Phone: " + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.execute();


}

private List<Node> getNodes() {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult rawNodes =
            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
    for (Node node : rawNodes.getNodes()) {
        nodes.add(node);
        nodeID = node.getId();
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

And here is how I **Receive** on my activity that implements MessageApi.MessageListener:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    Log.d("DEVELOPER", "......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!");


}
```

My output on send side looks like:

```
07-11 10:54:57.646  26920-28711/com.wearTest.message V/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Phone: Sending Msg: testMessage to node:  6ecc099a-60f8-4c3d-90fe-fa2f248c6bf7
07-11 10:54:57.666  26920-26920/com.wearTest.message V/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Phone: null
```

And the receive side logs:

```
07-11 10:54:57.962    5509-5672/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.962    5509-5610/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.962    5509-5660/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.962    5509-5521/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.962    5509-5539/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5570/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5604/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5601/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5566/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5520/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5582/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.972    5509-5567/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:57.982    5509-5587/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:58.002    5509-5581/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:58.052    5509-5581/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:58.052    5509-5587/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
07-11 10:54:58.062    5509-5570/com.wearTest.message D/DEVELOPER﹕ ......Wear: successfully received phone to wear communication!
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just in case, did you check that you're registering the receiver only once?

Comment: Ah thanks matiash! Bonehead move, that was it.

Comment: I'm glad it was that easy. :) Are you planning to delete this question, or should I add an answer?

Comment: Go ahead and add an answer for me to accept...it will save some other poor soul an hour of fruitless work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MessageApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html) should be working fine. Just be careful to call [`addListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html#addListener(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi.MessageListener)) only once, or you will get notified multiple times.

Alternatively, add matching `removeListener()` calls (for example in `onResume()` / `onPause()`).